# Navbar collapses to early and position my image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two questions. The first one is my navbar seems to be collapsing too late when you make the page smaller forcing the text to go under the search bar. How do i fix this? My second problem is how do i move my image slider over about 30 inches and make it have the same positioning effect it as right now? I am also using twitter bootstrap 3 i have also disabled responsiveness.

-Thanks for your help

Link to my site: http://rootforsite.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Please add some code so that we can look into what you have tried so far.

Comment: Also for your first question, do you want to collapse your navbar as soon as user resize browser?

Comment: yes and for the code just click the link and press f12

Comment: You can also try changing the min-width specified in the @media query. Because after this min-width the navbar will collapse. If your website intended for large screen devices you can set it to 1200px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the `.bx-wrapper img` a width of 100% if you want it to fit the whole slider.

```
.bx-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

As for the navbar, maybe someone could chime in on a better 'Bootstrap-way' to do this, but you can utilize a media query to position that menu absolutely on the right until it collapses.

```
@media (min-width:991px) {
  .navbar-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks the navbar works now, but for the image slider i didn't want to reposition the image inside of the image slider i wanted to move the whole image slider together just a bit over on my screen.